# Creating loops to update a label in app jar

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to make a countdown timer in appJar and have a label that shows how much time is remaining until the end of the allotted amount of time. I've looked at the guides on appJar's website a fair amount and know of the two ways that they say you can create loops with their library. You can use `.registerevent(function)` or `.after(delay_ms, function, *args)`. I've tried both of these ways and can't get either to work. I haven't managed to figure out how to get the `.after` function to work and every time I try to use the `.registerevent` function something doesn't work. My current issue is that I can get the function to *run* but it isn't actually *working*. That is, it says the block of code is running but the GUI ins't updating

Here are the specific lines of code in question

```
def introduction_bill(x):
    global time_remaining, time_allotted
    time_remaining = 120
    time_allotted = 120
    app.removeAllWidgets()
    print("ran 'introduction_bill'")
    app.addLabel('timer', 'Time remaining: 2:00')
    app.addButtons(['start timer','update'], [start_timer, update_timer])
    app.addButton('next introduction', next_introduction)

....

def update_timer():
    global time_remaining, current_function
    current_function = 'update timer'
    time_remaining = end_time - t.time()
    minutes = int(time_remaining // 60)
    seconds = round(time_remaining % 60, 2)
    app.setLabel('timer', 'Timer remaining: ' + str(minutes) + ':' + str(seconds))
    print("ran 'update_timer'")
    if time_remaining > -10:
        app.registerEvent(update_timer)


def start_timer(x):
    print("ran 'start_timer'")
    global start_time, end_time
    start_time = t.time()
    end_time = start_time + time_allotted
    update_timer()
```

And [here](https://pastebin.com/KZQH27Yt) is the code in its entirety

Keep in mind that I am still a beginner in coding so this code is both incomplete and very rough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve what you want with both of the methods you mention.

With `registerEvent()` you should only call it once, it then takes care of scheduling your function. In your code, you are calling it repeatedly, which won't work.

With `after()` you have to take care of calling it again and again.

So, with your current code, you're better off using `after()`:

In `update_timer()` try changing the call to `app.registerEvent(update_timer)` to be `app.after(100, update_timer)`

The timer should then update every 0.1 seconds.

However, if you click the **Start Timer** button again, you'll run into problems, so you might want to disable the button until the timer finishes.

Comment: Ok, I swore that I had tried that but I guess I put something in wrong. It works now though! Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear it - please accept my answer if you're happy.